# Remarketing audiences in Google Analytics and automation

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to automatically create remarketing audiences in Google Analytics using Analytics API? For example if certain page has 100 visits then create remarketing audience. It could be useful for bigger websites.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to coding. Please repost this in Webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

As noted in the comment,  the [August 8, 2016 release added Remarketing Audiences to the Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/changelog):

> The Management API allows you to create, get, list, update and patch
>   remarketing audiences for a Google Analytics property. To learn more
>   about how remarketing audiences work, see the About Remarketing
>   Audiences in Analytics help center article.

Delete support was added later. My old answer is thereby invalidated.

---

Old answer

While I disagree with the close vote (API programming seems to be perfectly on-topic) the [Management API is rather well documented](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/) and it says nothing about remarketing audiences, so the answer is "no".

Besides this might be less useful than you imagine. You want to re-engage audiences that abandoned a promising conversion path. With the careful analysis this requires actually setting up the audience would be the smallest of your tasks, plus the definitions for your audiences probably do not change all that often.

If you want to automate remarketing you might consider setting up a [smart goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6153083?hl=en), which automatically covers the most likely conversion paths (this is a configuration issue however, and would be really off-topic on SO).

Comment: Google has updated there documentation. [Remarketing Audiences](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/remarketingAudience/insert)

Comment: @CLOUGH, thank you.  The feature wasn't there when the question was asked, I have added the relevant excerpt from the changelog.

Comment: But PHP sample codes provided in that documentation are wrong. I think they have mixed it with JAVA sample code. [PHP sample codes for creating  remarketing audiences](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)